# Use @Path-Annotation from abstract Superclass in Swagger

Tags: java, resteasy, wildfly, swagger

I am currently testing the integration of swagger in my webframework. For better understanding i will first describe the architecture a little bit:
We have a basic web-api as a maven project which provides basic webservices based on Generic-Types. Then i have an API maven project where an abstract websevice class extends the webservice described above and provides the generic types (timeseries in my case) and adds a few additional webservices. And third i have my example implementation where a webservice class with a @Path- Annotation on class level extends the abstract class from the API and hence gets the Paths from the superclasses (create, get and other standard operations from the first framework and context relevant operations from the second API).
For documentation of this API i want to use swagger. I added the needed dependencies for swagger-jaxrs and swagger-annotations (both in version 1.5.3-M1) and put the BeanConfig in my Application. I also get the generated API if, and only if, i annotate my implementating classes method with @Path - Annotations. The problem with this is that i can not access my API because Wildfly can´t resolve the method to use (because i declared the @Path at two different levels i guess).
So my question is: is such a setup possible with swagger or do i have to have @Path-Annotations at the level of the @ApiX-Annotations of swagger?
Side-Note: The setup is wanted to have an API that has the given paths as a MUST so you can change the implementations but don´t have to change the clients (e.g. for different databases or business models)
Thanks for any answers :)
EDIT: ok so i found my initial error: if i specify the path at the method in the subclass i need to specify all other jax-rs annotations as well. But my question stays the same: can i get swagger to use the jax-rs annotations of the superclasses in any way?